# How to center and format my introduction the same as my chapters in my TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I want a center-aligned TOC. My MWE formats my chapters the way I want but not my introduction? How would I also format my introduction to match?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

% TOC title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}%
\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

% Document
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}  
\chapter{Where it All Began}
\chapter{Some More Beginning}
\chapter{Some Drawn-Out Diatribe}
\chapter{Starting to Wrapup}
\chapter{The Insightful Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

% TOC title
%\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}%
    \hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction} 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}Introduction}% changed <<<<<
    \chapter{Where it All Began}
    \chapter{Some More Beginning}
    \chapter{Some Drawn-Out Diatribe}
    \chapter{Starting to Wrapup}
    \chapter{The Insightful Conclusion}
\end{document}
```