# Memoir: Centered two-line parts with ordinal part numbers in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I'm trying to format my table of contents to use two-line, centered entries with ordinal numbers for part and chapter numbers. The entries should also be hyperlinks. I have managed to string together [an answer by Simon Dispa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675700/71332) that edits the chapters with [an altogether different one by daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584917/71332) that edits the parts to achieve something that looks pretty nice, but lacks the ordinal part numbers and the hyperlinks. Also, it would be nice to get rid of the page numbers for the parts.

When I try to use `fmtcount`'s `\Ordinalstringnum` in the redefinition of `\partnumberline`, I get an error. And when I load `hyperref` the formatting of the part entries fall apart.

**Output**
[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{fmtcount}
% \usepackage{hyperref}% Messes up the formatting

\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\cftchapterfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{\ }
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnumb}{\newline\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{\space—\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftchapterleader}\nobreak%
  {#1}%
  \cftchapterafterpnum\par%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\l@chapapp}[3]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \cftchapterbreak
    \vskip\cftbeforechapterskip%
    \centering%
    {\memRTLrightskip0pt%
     \@afterindenttrue%
     \interlinepenalty\@M%
     \leavevmode%
     \let\@cftbsnum\cftchapterpresnum
     \let\@cftasnum\cftchapteraftersnum%
     \let\@cftasnumb\cftchapteraftersnumb%
     \def\@chapapp@head{}%
     {\cftchapterfont#1}\nobreak%
     \cftchapterfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{%
  \chapternumberlinehook{#1}%
  \hb@xt@\@tempdima{\hfil\@chapapp@head\@cftbsnum {\itshape\MakeLowercase{\Ordinalstringnum{#1} chapter}}\@cftasnum\hfil}%
  \@cftasnumb}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\cftpartleader}{\space—\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfillnum}[1]{%
  {\cftpartleader}\nobreak%
  {#1}%
  \cftpartafterpnum\par%
}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{0em}
\setlength{\cftpartindent}{0em}
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{%
  \centering
  \normalsize\bfseries Part~#1
  \normalfont\bfseries
  \par
}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartformatpnum}[1]{\enspace\textperiodcentered\enspace#1}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% patch \l@part to remove some grouping

\patchcmd\l@part{%
  {\cftpartfont {#1}}\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{%
  #1\cftpartfillnum{#2}%
}{\typeout{patched}}{\FAILED}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \tableofcontents*
  \chapter{Introduction}
  \chapter{Preface}

  \mainmatter
  \part{The Beginning}
  \chapter{Where It All Began}
  \chapter{Some More Beginning}

  \part{The Climax}
  \chapter{Some Drawn-Out Diatribe}

  \part{The End}
  \chapter{Starting to Wrap Up}
  \chapter{The Insightful Conclusion}

  \backmatter
  \chapter{Some notes}
\end{document}
```

**Desired output**
[image: Desired output]

Comment: Do you mind explaining exactly what the expected output it? Preferably with a drawing/image.

Comment: @daleif I’ll be sure to do that as soon as I’m back at my computer. Back the essence of it is this: I’d like for “Part I” to read “First part”, “Part II” “Second part”, etc. And I’d like to remove the dash and page number from each part title row.

Comment: For parts `\Ordinalstringnum` fails as the arg is not a number it is a roman numerial

Comment: @daleif That seems reasonable :-D I have updated the question with an image of the desired output

Comment: My answer does seem to do that and works with `hyperref`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the part stuff as I understand the question, had to make my own  Roman to text as `fmtcounter` expects a number not a letter.

(edit: simpler helper)

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\RomanToText{m}{\Ordinalstringnum{\int_from_roman:n {#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{\RomanToText{#1}~part\par}
\renewcommand\cftpartfont{\par\centering}% the starting \par is needed
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd\l@part{%
  \cftpartfont {#1}%
}{%
  \cftpartfont #1\par%
}{\typeout{l@part patched}}{\typeout{l@part patch failed}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: A minor improvement would be to patch to `\ctfpartfont {#1}\par%` instead to retain the possibility that the very last element `\ctfpartfont` may be a macro that takes one argument.

Comment: Also if it is not necessary that parts should elsewhere be numbered using roman numerals, one could do `\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}` and then just change `\RomanToText{#1}` to `\Ordinalstringnum{#1}`